# DRF SERILAZATION

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I serialize the field named "product" with ProductSerializer() inside OrderItemSerializer().

That's what I want.

```
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = models.OrderItem
        fields = ('id','order', 'product', 'quantity')
```

The output is;

[image: Response of POST Method]

But when I try to request with POST Method needs to send Product as a dictionary, just giving the id value is not enough.

[image]

How can I POST by sending only the id value?

I haven't written anything about the operation yet. Default ModelViewSet

```
class OrderItemViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = OrderItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.OrderItemSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrNot, IsAuthenticated)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return self.filter_queryset(queryset=self.queryset.filter(order__user=self.request.user))
```

Comment: show us the  corresponding `view`, with your buisness logic

Comment: I haven't written anything about the operation yet. Default ModelViewSet

`class OrderItemViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = OrderItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.OrderItemSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrNot, IsAuthenticated)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return self.filter_queryset(queryset=self.queryset.filter(order__user=self.request.user))
`

Comment: please edit your post, and add this data from your comment to your question, it is important part of question

Comment: i've already did it

Comment: Do you want to create a `Product` also when creating an `OrderItem`?

Comment: No, what I want is that when i dont use product = ProductSerializer() inside OrderItemSerializer()

in POST method body i can send {"product": 1} (just product's id) but when i use that
product = ProductSerializer() inside OrderItemSerializer() i have to send in POST method's body product instance. Just product's id is not enough anymore. But i just want to use only id. I just asked is there anyway to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're supporting [writable nested representations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations) you'll need to write .create() or .update() methods that handle saving multiple objects.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'profile']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Profile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
        return user
```